# Interactive barplot in latex

Tags: overleaf, graphs, animations, interaction

How can I implement an interactive bar chart in latex,
specifically in overleaf ? In R I can use the plotly library, and in latex what library can I use and how can I implement it?

If you select the color, the bar plot change interactively.

[image]

Comment: LaTeX outputs to pdf, which is a static format. Therefore you cannot use interactive elements. There are some exceptions to this principle using JavaScript inside of the pdf and/or plugins for certain objects (like 3d models that can be rotated interactively). However, these features have rather limited viewer support (mostly Adobe Reader only).

Comment: In Overleaf you can use .Rtex documents with R code chukns that allow dynamical content, but once compiled (exported to PDF via LateX with knitr)  the R output is static. R interactive elements as  a plot at best will produce a screenshot in PDF format.